# Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$compile/multidir?p0=category&

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive

I have a main.jsp page in which i have multiple model(bootstrap dialog).
Every model have their own module and controller.

Suppose I open one model and just close it. After that I open second model so at that time that conflict occurs due to same service injected in both modules or model.

For first model I wrote

```
angular.module('model1', [
    'dir.scrolltable',
    'ui.sortable'
    ]);
```

For second model I wrote

```
angular.module('model2', [
    'dir.scrolltable']);
```

So for above two models 'dir.scrolltable' is common. So when i navigate from one model to secone this error comes.

Because at that time page is not refreshing. So second module tries to inject same service.

So is it possible to check the service already existed. So we can inject carefully.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think the diagnosis of your error - namely that AngularJS tries to inject the service twice holds true - simply because they are two different modules. You may have some other problem and checking if a service has been injected may not be the solution here

Comment: My main.jsp have its own module too. So if I wrote all dependency there, then it is fine. But I have requirement to separatre dependency as per model.